Show UI message when cell value is a multiple of ten 10, 20, 30
I have an spreadsheet that I am training some colleagues on, and during the exercise I want to encourage them by showing the UI message when they have completed typing (10 or 20 sentences or more, for example), and this cell in which the number is located is a group equation from another tab in the same sheet.

I want to show the UI message when they have completed typing (10 or 20 sentences or more).

Rightio. Ok, I think that I understand your scenario. What exactly is the problem that you’re having?

Thank you dear Tedinoz for following my question. I appreciate that. I think the answer close to what is required has been explained by colleague Wicket.

In Google Sheets, there is no way to show a message while the user is typing and reaches a threshold like ten words or any other. For this, create a dialog using the HTML Service and client-side HTML and JavaScript, including an input or text area elements where the user does the typing task. If needed, the dialog might send the user input to the spreadsheet.
It's worth noting that it's possible to show a message after the user has edited a cell or range.

The simplest way in Google Sheets using Apps Script to show a UI message after a user edited a cell or range is to use the onEdit simple trigger and SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.toast("message").
Example:
/**
 * Every time a new value is entered by a user on the keyboard in any cell, a toast will be shown.
 * @param {Object} e Edit event object. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#Google%20Sheets-events
 */
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.value) {
   const message = "The new cell value is " + e.value;
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message);
  }
}

To show the toast when the cell value meets a specific condition, use JavaScript to create the conditional expression.

Google Apps Script has several ways to show a "UI message" in Google Sheets. The documentation includes a guide for this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs. To show it automatically it has two types of triggers, simple and installable. For this, there are three guides:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers,
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Class Browser
From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser

This class provides access to dialog boxes specific to Google Sheets.
The methods in this class are only available for use in the context of a Google Spreadsheet. Please use Google Workspace dialogs instead.

Methods

SpreasheetApp.Spreadsheet.toast(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(...)

For details, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui
The documentation of some methods includes examples.
Note: The methods that make use of the HTML Service are

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(...)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(...)

Also, you might use the Card Service, but this is more complex than the methods mentioned above, as this service requires the creation of a Workspace Add-on. The user should manually open the Add-on, and the cards might be updated after the user does something on one of the cards.

I have created a spreadsheet for demoing purposes. At the time of updating this answer, it includes a bound script that adds a custom menu with an option that opens a modal dialog having a text box. Below the text box is a word counter. I might extend it later to show message when a threadhold is reached.
Clicking the below link will open a page to make a copy of the spreadsheet.
Copy Demo spreadsheet

Copy the spreadsheet.
Please be patient it might take a few seconds to create the the copy.
The copy will be opened once it be ready. Later you could find it on https://sheets.google.com and in https://drive.google.com with the name Copy of Demo - Utilities.

Once the spreadsheet opens, wait a bit to allow the Utilities custom menu to load.

Highly Suggested Review the code before running the script. For this, click Extensions then Apps Script. The Google Apps Script contained project will be open.

Once you find yourself confortable with the code included in the project, go back to the spreadsheet and click Utilities then Word Counter.
The first time that a function that requires authorization to run is executed, if the script was not already authorized, a prompt asking for authorization will be shown. Each user should authorize the script before being able to using it. If the authorization prompt was shown, please click again Utilities then Word Counter.
If the authoriztion was granted, the modal dialog described on top of this section will be shown.

Type on the text box. The word count will be updated once a white space character is entered like a space, break line, etc.

To close the dialog click the X button on the top-right corner.



HTML + JavaScript
Below there is a extract of the Google Apps Script project including only the client side HTML and JavaScript.


const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', showWordCount);
const displayer = document.querySelector('span');

function showWordCount(e) {
  displayer.innerText = countWords(textarea.value);
}

function countWords(str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.") {
  return str.trim().match(/\S\s|.$/g)?.length
}
<p>The word count is shown below the text box.</p>
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px"></textarea>
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0px;">Word Count: <span>0</span></div>



Related

Show Alert Popup when cell selection is changed (onSelectionChange)


Thank you so much dear Wicket for answering my question and your guides to me.

That's right, Wicket. You drew my attention to something I was looking for but did not notice. I tried to vote on the answer but I did not reach the level, but you kindly made it clear to me the point of agreeing to the answer. Thank you.
